# Laravel 5.4 LengthAwarePaginator

Tags: laravel

My brain suddenly crashed on this one. Anyone care to help me is highly appreciated.

This is LengthAwarepaginator in laravel 5.4

Here is the code.

```
$collection = [];

            foreach ($maincategories->merchantCategory as $merchantCat) {

               foreach ($merchantCat->merchantSubcategory as $merchantSub) {

                   foreach($merchantSub->products as $products){

                        $collection[] = $products;
                   }
               }
            }

            $paginate = new LengthAwarePaginator($collection, count($collection), 10, 1, ['path'=>url('api/products')]);

            dd($paginate);
```

It displays perfectly but the problem is the items is 100. That's all my items and I specify it correctly. I need to display only 10.

Base on LengthAwarePaginator constructor. Here is the reference.

```
public function __construct($items, $total, $perPage, $currentPage = null, array $options = [])
```

Here is the screen shot.

[image]

Where did I go wrong? TY

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When manually creating a paginator, you have to slice the result set yourself. The first parameter to the paginator should be the desired page of results, not the entire result set.

From the [pagination documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator):

> When manually creating a paginator instance, you should manually "slice" the array of results you pass to the paginator. If you're unsure how to do this, check out the [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) PHP function.

I would suggest using a `Collection` to help out with this a little:

```
// ...

$collection = collect($collection);

$page = 1;
$perPage = 10;

$paginate = new LengthAwarePaginator(
    $collection->forPage($page, $perPage),
    $collection->count(),
    $perPage,
    $page,
    ['path' => url('api/products')]
);
```

Comment: Thanks... I've got it and here is the link. http://psampaz.github.io/custom-data-pagination-with-laravel-5/

Comment: @Rbex That article is a little old. I've updated my answer with some newer collection code (namely the `forPage()` method).

Comment: much easier compared to the link. Anyway thank you so much. You're a rockstar!

Comment: This was such a great find - been grinding away on this for a few hours. Thanks a million @patricus

Comment: Holy Moly, I've been searching this for years!

Answer (score 1):

For the heavy select and to avoid any multiple select to calculate the total from the table we unable to use model paginate

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
```

in your controller function

```
if(!isset($input["total"])){ //initial request
         $total = //Find the total only one time.
         $request->request->add(['total' => $total]); //Add it in the request so that we can print it in blade 
}else
         $total = $input["total"];  //After initial request

$currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage(); //page variable from GET or POST
$perPage = 30; //Page Length 
$offset = ($currentPage - 1) * $perPage; //find the offset to pass in query
$specificRecords = /*Collect specific page records in array 
if mysql then Select * from table limit $perPage offset $offset 
if ms sql then OFFSET {$offset} ROWS FETCH NEXT {$perPage} ROWS ONLY */
$records = new LengthAwarePaginator($specificRecords,$total,$perPage,Null,[ "path" => "/pagepath" ]);
```

in blade:

```
<center>{{$records->appends(Request::except([ 'page','_token' ]))->links()}}</center>
```

Check Page and total variable in page tags ensure you added page in except list :)